# When using RestSharp, I am getting MethodNotFound on a POST but the response thinks its a GET?

Tags: c#, restsharp, methodnotfound

I am using RestSharp and doing a POST for the first time I have a number of GET requests that all work fine).  The Rest Service is in python but I don't think thats critical to the question.  Here is my code:

```
   var client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = _baseUrl };

  var request = new RestRequest("nameOfPostMethod", Method.POST);
  request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  request.AddBody(new { name, description });
  request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

  var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Here is the raw response I get:

```
    [{"name": "405 - Method Not Allowed", "data": 
    [["Class", "werkzeug.exceptions.MethodNotAllowed"], ["Category", "Client Error"], 
     ["Code", "405"], ["Name", "Method Not Allowed"], ["request.method", "GET"], 
     ["request.url", "http://myUrl/nameOfPostMethod"], ["error.message", "405 Method
    Not Allowed"], ["error.description", null]]}]
```

the thing that stick out at me are these line where it seems to think I am doing a GET instead of a POST:

```
 ["request.method", "GET"]

 ["error.message", "405 Method Not Allowed"]
```

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong here?

### UPDATE:

I downloaded fiddler and tried to see whats going on and interestingly when i look at the headers, it does show a GET.  Here is a screenshot for what I see in fiddler:

[image]

I even tried to change:

```
  client.Execute(request);
```

to

```
  client.Post(request);
```

but it still shows the same thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used something like fiddler to capture the request to see if it is doing a get rather than a post?

Comment: Does the REST service have a GET method with the same name by any chance?

Comment: @Ben Robinson - I tried using Fiddler and it DOES show it as a GET . . any clue why that would happen given the code above?

Comment: @BenRobinson - i included a fiddler screenshot to show you what i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out it was a redirect issue on the webserver side so nothing to do with Rest Sharp

I have requested to delete the question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a cross-domain request?  If so, then I suspect that RestSharp is making a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) preflight request before doing the actual HTTP POST.  "405 Method Not Allowed" is the proper response to a CORS request if a cross-domain POST is not allowed.  I am unsure if that screen shot is showing *all* the HTTP headers.  Does it send the  Access-Control-* headers in the GET?  That would confirm it.